# Best practice for environments with Xero-API development?

Tags: xero-api

We are coding against the JDE API using the Demo system for our own company.  But this is just one environment.  For our real work we generally have Dev, UAT, and Prod.  Does anyone know how best to do this with Xero?  Should we sign up three times, one for each environment?  This would be tedious to keep the systems in sync.
Or, does Xero have any concept of having these environments automatically set up?  Some cloud providers just do this automatically with a sandbox refreshed from production on-demand or on a schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xero does not have sandbox environments. The closet would be the Demo Company which can be refreshed via the UI.

If you were wanting separate keys/secrets for each of your environments you could create 3 apps.

If you want this as a feature here are some Uservoice links that you can add your vote to: https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/3077195-allow-the-demo-company-to-be-reset-without-data and https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/7361125-simplify-testing-endpoint-to-reset-all-demo-acco

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  What I'm really looking for is a refresh from Production, not a reset.  I'll make a UserVoice request.